# gnome-terminal does not differentiate between C-d and C-S-d

Tags: gnome-terminal, tmux

When I run `cat` on gnome-terminal, both <kbd>C-d</kbd> and <kbd>C-S-d</kbd> terminate it. This is because gnome-terminal cannot distinguish between these keys and sends and EOF in both the cases. Is there a ways I can configure this and tell gnome-terminal to differentiate these keys.

The reason I am asking for this is because I use *tmux* in gnome-terminal and I'd like to bind tmux actions to <kbd>C-S-z</kbd>, <kbd>C-S-d</kbd> etc., but doing so renders the non-shift variants of those keys to the same tmux bindings. In other words, I want <kbd>C-S-d</kbd> to do a tmux action that I bind, but <kbd>C-d</kbd> to send an EOF. Currently, both these key combinations do the same thing, whatever it may be.

Someone on IRC freenode.net#tmux suggested that gnome-terminal might be sending the same key codes for both these key combinations and so tmux is unable to distinguish between them. I also learnt that *xterm* and *rxvt* can be configured to do this, but I'd like to know if gnome-terminal can do it.

Any ideas ont hsi appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need <kbd>C-d</kbd> at all (you can close a terminal with `exit`, after all), you could try to remove its association with EOF, and associate EOF with another unuseful sequence, <kbd>C-j</kbd> for example:

```
stty eof ^J
```

I cannot say if it also will free the use of <kbd>C-S-d</kbd>.

If it works, that command should be set in `~/.bashrc`, for example.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but I run many cli apps like mutt/vim/irssi etc., so, I'd still like to know if it could be done.